# Trying to find a transfer function from the discrete system below

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve the system below in Matlab. This system is a discrete system. I need to convert to a state space model system, to extract 4 matrices. Then find the transfer function.

```
y(k+2) + 4y(k+1) + 5y(k)= u(k+2)+2u(k+1)+u(k).
```

I solved this by hands and I found the four matrices:

```
A=[0,1:-5,-4]
B=[-2;4]
C=[1,0,0]
D=[1]
```

My problem is when I try to run my below code I got this error:

Error using `ss2tf` (line 26)
The A and C matrices must have the same number of columns.

Error in no1 (line 5)

```
[N1,D1]=ss2tf(A,B,C,D,1);
```

My Matlab code:

```
A=[0,1;-5,-4];
B=[-2;4];
C=[1,0,0];
D=[1];
[N1,D1]=ss2tf(A,B,C,D,1);
H=tf(N1,D1)
```

I expect to get a transfer function

Comment: As the error message suggests, `A` and `C` must have the same number of columns. You matrix `A` is of size 2x2 and you matrix `C` of size 1x3, hence the error. You have obviously made a mistake when solving by hand and calculating your matrices.

Comment: @am304 Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that you are dealing with a discrete-time system (add `1`as third argument to `ss2tf`). If you correct the `C` matrix as already noticed in the comment, then the following code will do what you want:

```matlab
A = [0,1;-5,-4];
B = [-2;4];
C = [1,0];
D = 1;
[N1,D1] = ss2tf(A,B,C,D);
H = tf(N1,D1,1)
```

```
H =

  z^2 + 2 z + 1
  -------------
  z^2 + 4 z + 5
```